# SSIS: Multiple Sources to 1 Destination

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb, etl

I am quite new to SSIS. I have multiple sources for example i have products in sql database and excel sheet and i need to migrate them both to 1 destination and that is another sql database. I have found some answers but they are the other way around 1 data source and multiple destinations but i can't seem to find my answer. At the bottom you can see how i am trying to do it right now. I hope someone can point me to right direction.

[image]

Comment: You didn't describe your problem. What problem are you having? What happens when you get the same product in two different sources that have different values?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i think he is asking if he is importing data in the right way?

Comment: To know the answer he just has to test what he has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 approaches to import data from multiple source into on destination table:

**(1) Run in parallel**

It is similar to the way you are achieving, [but you may have to uncheck the table lock option](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121740/do-you-need-table-lock-when-you-have-multiple-ole-db-connections-inserting-to-th) from both destination which decrease performance.

**(2) Union All transformation**

In the data flow task add both sources then add a UNION ALL transformation to merge both sources into one flow, then map the output to the destination

- [Union All Transformation in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/union-all-transformation-in-ssis/)

**(3) Two consecutive data flows**

Add 2 data flow tasks in the package, on each data flow import one source to the destination. And map one data flow to the other using a precedence constraint. In this way, data is imported in 2 phases (each source in one phase)

Comment: Upvoted for not mentioning Merge transformation to the newbies. <3

Comment: @kudos it is better to use the other approaches from performance perspective

Comment: @Hadi Can you please recommend what approach should be taking in my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69920725/map-a-field-in-the-sql-db-to-another-table-field-by-look-up