# Map two source to the destination SQL DB table

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, etl, lookup

This is my first SSIS package any help is greatly appreciated. I have a flat file that needs to be inserted into the Azure DB. I have data from the flat file disassembled all the fields from this flat-file need to be mapped to the Azure DB table. The Flat file has the below fields like

[image]

Azure SQL DB Customer table

[image]

All fields from the flat file are mapped to the Azure SQL DB table, on the insert, I need to map the RoomID field to a different table  called RM_Room

```
SELECT [ROOMID]
      ,[NAME]
  FROM [dbo].[RM_Room]
```

when the Name on the [RM_Room] matches the Location field on the Customer. I am not sure how to lookup on the RM_Room table for every customer insert and bring the Room id when the fields match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lookup transformation to get the relevant ROOMID. Also, you can use a fuzzy lookup if different string may have the same value.

Please refer to the following article for more information:

- [SSIS Lookup transformation vs. Fuzzy Lookup transformation](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-lookup-transformations-vs-fuzzy-lookup-transformations/)